# How do I prepend a div with current year?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm somewhat new to JavaScript and jQuery

I'm using jQuery prepend() to create a new div with the class of "X" and inside the new div I need to have the result or the current year and a disclaimer.

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footer').prepend('<div class="disclaimer">current year + disclaimer text</div>');
});
```

So far I am able to create the new div inside the div with the disclaimer but not the current year.

My JavaScript for current year:

```
now = new Date
document.write(now.getFullYear())
```

Comment: Well for one, `new Date` does nothing. Secondly, you haven't asked a question, specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate that variable into the string:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var now = new Date()
    $('#footer').prepend('<div class="disclaimer">' + now.getFullYear() + ' + disclaimer text</div>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you I guess the answer whas so simple and right infront of me and I couldn't see it. This works Thank You again

Answer (score 2):

You mean

```
$(function() {
    $('#footer').prepend('<div class="disclaimer">'+
      new Date().getFullYear() + 
      ' disclaimer text</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just about as straightforward as your example. To play it safe (if you needed to have `<`, `>`, etc. in your disclaimer text, for instance), use `.text()` to add the contents:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var discText = "disclaimer text";
  var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

  $('<div class="disclaimer"></div>').
     text(currentYear + " - " + discText).
     appendTo('#footer');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<footer id="footer"></footer>
```